# Ubercart unable to send email

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

Upon completion of checkout I am getting the error message `unable to send email: contact-site administrator if the problem persists`.  When I check the dblog I get full error message is `Error sending e-mail (from Site Name <nameA@site.com> to nameA@site.com).`.  It seems to me that the problem could be related to the fact they they are trying to send the email to the same person as it is from.

What baffles me about this is that I am logged in as the administrator and it's my email as the site administrator and nameA is listed as the email on the store configurations.

The webform email is working fine (I am using the SMTP module)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my issue was with the SMTP authentication configuration.  Once I got that straightened out and change the site administration email to match that on the SMTP authentication configuration it worked just fine.